# Can figures and tables go past page limits?

Tags: publications, paper-submission, formatting

I'm writing a paper for a conference, and the tables and figures go past the page limit, but they end up in the references section. That is, our text does not go past the page limit, just a few tables.

Is this usually acceptable? Is there any standard guidance on whether or not this is okay, or does it often differ between conferences?

Comment: What exactly do the formatting guidelines say? You probably don't need any other information.

Comment: The answer to this question will depend entirely on where you are submitting the manuscript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is conference specific. I have seen calls for abstracts that explicitly say two, period, I have seen calls that say one page text, one page figures, plus references, so on and so forth.